# Building topological equivalence between two vector fields

Tags: general-topology, ordinary-differential-equations, linear-transformations, differential-topology

I'm reading about topological equivalence between different vector fields and I would like to know how to build these mappings. Let us consider one pedagogical example, suppose I have the following vector fields

$$
\dot{\vec{v}}_1 = (y,2x) \,\, , \quad \textrm{and} \quad \dot{\vec{v}}_2 = (w, Ku) \,\, ,
$$

with $K \in \mathbb{R}$. I would like to show that both vectors fields are topologically equivalent, then I think that showing the existence of an affine transformation from $\vec{h}: \vec{v}_1 \to \vec{v}_2$ is sufficient, once any affine transformation is homeomorphic. Let's suppose that the transformtion reads,

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
y \\x
\end{pmatrix} 
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
w \\
\frac{Ku}{2}
\end{pmatrix} \,\, .
$$

Is this reasoning right? Does the transformation I proposed satisfy the homeomorphic condition to topological equivalence? (I am not sure if the notation I used was suitable, actually I'm little rusty in this topic. Let me know there is something awkward with the maths).

Ps: two vector fields are topologically equivalent if there is a Homeomorphism between them, preserving direction of time.

Comment: On thing you should definitely include is a definition of "topological equivalence between vector fields"; without that, how does one know what to check regarding your proposed formula?

Comment: I don't believe this work. In general, if you map $(u,v)\rightarrow (u,Av)$ your field vector $(u,Kv)$ gets mapped to $(u, AKV)$, but at point $(y,x)=(w,Au)$ the vector field is expected to be $(y,2x) = (w, 2Au)$, so unless $K=2$ the mapping does not work. On the other hand, the homeomorphism does not have to be be induced by a mapping between $(y,x)$ and $(w,u)$.

Comment: @LeeMosher I have considered your point :)

Comment: @blamocur So,. Is there any way to create a Homeomorphism between these vector fields?  Could you please show me an example? :)

Comment: So, here's the main issue. The usual concept of a homeomorphism in the field of topology is a function whose domain and range are topological spaces, that function is a bijection, it is continuous, and its inverse is continuous. But a "vector field" is not a topological space, so that usual concept cannot be what you have in mind.

Comment: @HerrSchrödinger: $$u = x, w = y$$  $$ \dot\vec{v_{2,u}} = \frac{K}{2}\dot\vec{v_{1,x}}, \dot\vec{v_{2,w}} = \dot\vec{v_{1,y}}$$

Comment: Why do you have dots over the vector fields? And are they not both vector fields on $\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: I think you completely garbled the definition of topological equivalence of vector fields. The correct one is in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/111722/topological-equivalence-of-homotopic-vector-fields#:~:text=The%20vector%20fields%20are%20topologically,a%20topologically%20equivalent%20vector%20field.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thank you! Actually I Should create this homeomorphism between the solutions of the vector fields, these are defined over manifolds. I'll try to picture a way do make this.

Answer (score -1):

You can use separate mappings for the base $\mathbb R^2$ and the tangent space, whichg is also $\mathbb R^2$:

$$u = x, w = y$$

$$ \dot{\vec{v}}_{2,u} = \frac{K}{2}\dot{\vec{v}}_{1,x},
\;\;\;\;\dot{\vec{v}}_{2,w} = \dot{\vec{v}}_{1,y}$$